# Sending .csv file from linux to windows

Tags: linux, shell, csv, unix, scripting

I want to send files (`txt` or `csv`) from `linux` to `windows`.

I already have a script to get information and put it into a `.txt` or `.csv` file, tried with many ways to send this file from linux to my computer.

there is a *ping* from server to *my computer IP*, but when i use below commands it gives:

**ssh: connect to host 10.10.X.X port 22: Connection timed out**

> scp -r fname.lname@10.10.X.X:/home/ test.txt

or

> scp test.txt fname.lname@10.10.X.X:/C:/Data

Please could you help, simply I wanna have a copy of file *(that I have it in server)* in my computer, to use it.

*there is some similar questions with no answer here.*

Answer (score 1):

You need a ssh server installed on windows. Windows does not currently have out of the box ssh server. They are thinking of implementing OOB ssh servers in future releases of windows 10. 
Have a look at this link https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_windows_openssh_server

Also, if the file transfer that you want is a one time transfer, you can use putty with a reverse scp to retrieve the file or you can use WINscp ( https://winscp.net/eng/download.php )

Answer (score 0):

I usually use the command 'nc' for file transmission.
But since on Windows you have to install a cygwin to use nc, so I think the simplest solution may be like the following.
On linux, go to the directory of those files, and then type:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 1234
```

Then on windows you can visit 10.10.X.X:1234 in your browser, and download those files.

Note that 1234 can be replaced by any other port which is not currently used on linux.

Comment: thank you @Chen Zhu , but this it not worked with me.
i have `WinSCP` to upload/download but i want to make a shell script to get specific file from `Linux` to my computer.